# Counting with Case

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I've written a query that's meant to count records and return aggregated results. My goal is to count the number of types within a CASE I've written.

```html
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN ot.type = 1 THEN 'Card' WHEN ot.type = 2 THEN 'Cash' END) AS type, 
  YEAR(t.date) AS YEAR, 
  MONTH(t.date) AS MONTH, 
  COUNT(t.proccessed_id) 
FROM 
  transactions t 
  JOIN order_transactions ot ON t.id = ot.order_id 
WHERE 
  AND ot.type IN (1,2) 
  AND YEAR(t.date) = '2017' 
GROUP BY
  YEAR(t.date), 
  MONTH(t.date)
```

How can I count the number of records returned from my SUM(CASE?

Comment: Do you want the number of types, or the numbers per type? For the latter, see GMB's answer. For the former, try `COUNT(DISTINCT)` instead of `SUM()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query tries to sum strings (either `'Cash'` or '`Card`'). This does not make sense to your database.

I think that you want the count of each transaction type in two different columns. You can do this with expressions like:

```
select
    sum(ot.type = 1) cnt_card,
    sum(ot.type = 2) cnt_cash,
    year(t.date) as year, 
    month(t.date) as month, 
    count(t.proccessed_id)
from
-- ... the rest of your query
```